# Converting a file from Corel draw 7 to Corel draw 6

Tags: corel-draw

I have a version Corel draw 7 downloaded on my computer. I have done a project and saved it as a cdr. The problem is at tafe we have Corel draw 6. I would like to know how I can save this file and still open it in class with Corel draw 6. On my computer it has no option to save as Corel draw 6.

Comment: Why are you using software released in 1995 ??

Comment: I think you want to say X6 and X7, isn't it?

Comment: Hi Anna, please [edit] your answer to make it more clear what versions you're using. Is it really CorelDraw6 and 7?? Also what is a tafe?

Answer (score 1):

Corel Draw 7 is ancient!

But all versions can surely save to the previous version. I do not remember on that old version, but try to "save as". It should be a drop down menu somewhere.

My version can save up to 8 versions older.

[image]